# Using git, how can I save my progress (so that I can potentially rollback to it later) without committing?

Tags: git, squash

Sometimes in the course of development, I reach a certain point in trying to make something work where I decide to try something new.  I want to build on top of my current work (so `git stash` wouldn't work) and be able to roll back to the current state, if I decide my new approach is going nowhere. However, my current work is usually not in a state where I want to commit it and have it be in my commit history forever, since the point of trying something new is usually to fix something that's broken.

What would be the best course of action here? One thing I've considered is to commit it now, and then later if I succeed with my new approach, make another commit and squash those two together.  Is this the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: My recommendation is not to care too much about what's in the commit history.  Just create a new branch and develop the feature, and merge it using `git merge --no-ff` once the feature is complete, or simply drop the branch if you decide not to go ahead with it. In the latter case, nothing will remain in the commit history.

Comment: I make a lot of experimental branches. If the feature is named X, I wind up with `x.0`, `x.1`, `x.2`, and so on which are each attempt. I copy (rebase -i or individual git cherry-pick operations) the good parts and redo the bad parts until I have something that seems right, then construct the final series of commits from that and send or merge that final series when it's ready.

Comment: What @torek suggest is perfectly reasonable. `git stash` could still work though since you may `git stash save 'some reasonable message' && git stash apply` than you get to have your stash saved and have your changes to keep working with them. if you later decide that your current idea wasn't good after all you can `git reset --hard` and `git stash apply` and be exactly where you were. You may `git stash drop` once you know this stash isn't relevant anymore. Most of the times I still prefer branches but occasionally stashing is very handy in situations very similar to yours

Answer (score 2):

As you have yourself suggested squashing commits is one way to go about it.

Another alternative is to commit once and subsequently keep amending to the commit in chunks using the following:
`git commit --all --amend --no-edit`

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that do commit whenever you need! Commits do not hurt anything unless you push them to remote.

This is how I do usually, only with simple commands. I re-iterate your question to be sure: "*You find a new bug during a new feature development.*"

```
$ # coding but now you found a serious bug otherwise
$ # you cannot continue the feature development
$
$ git commit -m "(1) In the middle of feature development X"
$
$ # Making a bugfix
$ git add . && git commit -m "(2) Bugfix"
$
$ # Continue with your feature development
$ git commit -m "(3) Finished development X"
$
$ # origin -- (1) -- (2) -- (3)
```

Now if (2) is part of your feature development commit, you may want to squash it to one commit. If so,

```
$ git reset --soft (1)~1 # where (1) is a sha-1 of the commit (1)
$ git commit -m "Feature development X with a minor bugfix" # (4)
$
$ # origin -- (4)
```

Note that `git reset --soft` retains the current working directory state.
If (2) is independent of X but rather a common fix to the system, you make it like this:

```
$ git checkout (1)~1 # Go back to the original state
$ git cherry-pick (2)  # (2') First apply bugfix, expecting no conflict
$ git cherry-pick (1) && git cherry-pick (3)
$ git reset --soft HEAD^ && git commit --amend -m "A new feature X"  # (5)
$
$ # origin -- (2') -- (5)
```